# JavaScript scope issue/error

Tags: javascript, scope, this

I got at brainteaser in my mailbox, it is supposed to take 20 minutes but apparently, I got stuck at scope that I crashed Chrome. The idea is that a string is provided to you. You then use the string to generate random sentences akin to lorum ipsum.

```
var words = "The sky above the port was the color of television, tuned to a 
dead channel. All this happened, more or less. I had the story, bit by bit, 
from various people, and, as generally happens in such cases, each time it 
was a different story. It was a pleasure to burn.";

var wordList = words.split(' ');
var numWords = getRandomInt(2, 8);
var numSentinces = getRandomInt(8, 40);
var sentinces = [];
var sentince = [];

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
function genSentinces() {
   while (numWords > 0) {
      sentince.push(wordList[getRandomInt(0, wordList.length)]);
      numWords--;
   }
   sentince = sentince.join(' ');
   console.log(sentince)
   return sentince;
}
genSentinces();
genSentinces();
```

I am assuming that the scope of the sentence variable is wrong as it runs the first time but not the second time. I think I need to add a this somewhere.
Any help would be appreciated, as I can read code that has this in it but I apparently can't write code with this yet.

Comment: In you code change this `sentince.push` to `sentinces.push` and same with join statement on the right side of assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The main mistake is that you forget, that if you will modify global variable (all variables outside your functions can be called "global" regarding to this functions), it will not take the original value without your intervention. For example, if you declare new variable outside the function like `var x = 0;`, and then modify this variable from within the function like `x = 1`, this variable will be equal to `1` now.

1. You init `sentince` variable as array (`var sentince = [];`), but after the first execution of `genSentinces` function, this variable will be a string (because you're doing `sentince = words.join(' ')`). For this reason, I declared new array `words` inside the function, and I push words to it instead of pushing to global `sentince` array.
2. You use `numWords--` to decrease the counter on every loop iteration, but `numWords` is a global variable and it will still equal to `0` after the first function invocation (it's why I added `numWords = getRandomInt(2, 8)` after the loop).

Here is the working example, feel free to ask, if anything isn't clear:

```js
var words = "The sky above the port was the color of television, tuned to a dead channel. All this happened, more or less. I had the story, bit by bit, from various people, and, as generally happens in such cases, each time it was a different story. It was a pleasure to burn.";

var wordList = words.split(' ');
var numWords = getRandomInt(2, 8);
var numSentinces = getRandomInt(8, 40);
var sentinces = [];
var sentince = [];

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
function genSentinces() {
   var words = [];
   while (numWords > 0) {
      words.push(wordList[getRandomInt(0, wordList.length)]);
      numWords--;
   }
   numWords = getRandomInt(2, 8);
   sentince = words.join(' ');
   console.log(sentince)
   return sentince;
}
genSentinces();
genSentinces();
```

Answer (score 0):

You changed variable 'sentince' from array to string and when you call function second time you call 'sentince.push(...' to string type and variable variable 'numWords' equal to 0 after first call.